# AASM: Transitions from any state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, aasm

I am using [AASM](https://github.com/rubyist/aasm). Is it possible to transition from any state? For example:

```
aasm_event :publish do
  transitions :to => :publish, :from => ANY_STATE
end
```

I know that it is possible to pass an array of states to `:from`, but this isn't what I'm after. I have tried omitting the `:from` completely, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

aasm now supports transitions without any `from` specified, which will allow transitioning from any state.

```ruby
aasm_event :publish do
  transitions to: :publish # from ANY
end
```

(bragging rights: I added this feature because I needed it)

Comment: Thanks for adding the feature to the codebase. All AASM releases >= 3.0.10 include this now.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the states via the `aasm_states` class method, provided they have already been defined earlier in the code.

```
aasm_event :publish do
  transitions :to => :publish, :from => aasm_states.map(&:name)
end
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but feels hack-ish. AASM should support :all or :any.